# Need help understanding this hadith?

Tags: hadith, practical-islam, houri

*It was narrated from Mu'adh bin Jabal that: the Messenger of Allah said: "No woman annoys her husband but his wife among houris (of Paradise) safs: 'Do not annoy him, may Allah destroy you, for he is just a temporary guest with you and soon he will leave you and join us."'*

Does this mean that the our husbands in this life won’t be with us in Jannah, and instead with the houris, who are superior to women in this dunya?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Does this mean that the our husbands in this life won’t be with us in Jannah, and instead with the houris, who are superior to women in this dunya?**

No. If a husband and his wife both enter Jannah, they will stay married in Jannah as well.

However, the meaning of this hadith is about the wife not entering Jannah presumably (in the context of this hadith) due partly to her bad behavior with her husband.

Answer (score 0):

This mean , if a Muslim’s wife enters Jannah, then he will marry her.

If she enters Jannah and he did not enter, God Almighty creates a husband for her